# Is it correct to say that 1 meter of water weighs as much as 1000 meters of air?

Tags: gravity, pressure

Pressure $1$ meter under water is approx $1.1$ atm ($1$ atm due to air, $0.1$ atm due to water), and pressure $1000$ meters above water is approx $0.9$ atm.

So, roughly speaking, is it correct to say that $1$ meter of water (indipendently from cross-sectional area) weighs as much as $1000$ meters of air?

For example, a cubic metre of water weighs $1000$ kg, while a column of a square metre base and $1000$ meters height weighs $1225$ kg (using constant air density at 15°C, which is wrong since temperature will decrease with height)

Comment: Yes. But since "1 meter of water (independently from cross-sectional area)" is long winded and confusing, it might be better to say "the *density* of water is 1000 times bigger than the density of air" (The actual values are 1000 kg/m^3 and about 1.2 kg/m^3 at sea level atmospheric conditions).

Comment: Your phrasing implies a dimensional inconsistency, so others will not immediately understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly yes.

The air density varies with altitude and temperature but for 1000m the effect is still relatively small. Density at ground level is $1.22kg/m^3$ and at 1000m it's still $1.11kg/m^3$ (see https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/standard-atmosphere-d_604.html) so it's closer to 850m of air but it's in the right ballpark